# Dropbox using flask

Tags: python, flask, dropbox

I am going through the dropbox api and trying to alter the code so I can use it with flask. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#python

All I was put a callback in the link to dropbox:

```
<a href="{{url}}&oauth_callback=http://127.0.0.1:5000/">
```

which puts the id and oauthtoken in the url. I then check to see if the token is there with:

```
 success=request.args.get('oauth_token')
```

('oauth_token') doesn't display in the url if the user hits deny. So then I have:

```
if success:
    access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
```

But I get a token is disabled or invalid error when I do that. If anyone can point me to exactly what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it. I don't understand why I'd get an invalid or disabled token if the user is hitting allow on the dropbbox page.

Comment: Try using [Flask-OAuth](http://packages.python.org/Flask-OAuth/) instead. There's also a [Flask-Dropbox](https://github.com/playpauseandstop/Flask-Dropbox) extension.

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out. Do you have any idea why it's failing? Just for my own edification.